# How to prove that `fake.unique.ascii_free_email()` will never return a duplicate email address no matter how many times its run

Tags: python, faker

- I want to understand and prove via some results that in no case the
  email address returned by this [faker provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.internet.html?highlight=email#) will return a
  duplicate email for a run session
- I tried running the below snippet and found that there was no
  duplicate in list of 20 result emails  but i want to ask if there is
  a way by which I can prove for certain that lets say if I run this
  snippet for N number of times then there will be no duplicates in the
  list of N resultant emails

```
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

def test_faker():
    for _ in range(20):
        print(fake.unique.ascii_free_email())
```

Comment: Why do you want to prove this? If your underlying goal is to avoid dupes, why not add a set and re-generate any that are already in the set until you hit the desired quantity? "Never generate a dupe" is a lot to hope for. There are a finite number of ASCII characters in bounded length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what fake.unique does. The UniqueProxy wraps every fake method with a decorator that ensures that within this run that each value is only ever returned once. See https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/proxy.py

Comment: So it turns out that `fake.unique.ascii_free_email()` is not really unique and does return quite duplicate values if used for generating large amounts of test emails so I used another approach of creating unique emails by adopting something like this `return "test-{}@gmail.com".format(uuid4().hex)`